# Fonts not loading on iOS but load fine in Android

Tags: ios, qt, fonts

I'm currently loading two fonts from a qrc file. One of them is .ttf and the other is .otf. When I test my build on Android, they load and work fine (although the loading time is fairly long..)

However when I test it on my iPhone and/or simulator, none of the fonts load at all. They just seem to default back to Arial or something. Furthermore, only the .otf file works fine on Windows. The .ttf file defaults back to Arial and the characters are offset by 2 characters (so the word "ok" would be "qm")

What the hell is going on?
The fonts are located in:
"qrc:/fnt/res/fnt/MuseoSans_500.otf"
"qrc:/fnt/res/fnt/museo100-regular.ttf"

and I'm using this to load the fonts:

```
FontLoader {
    id: museosans500
    source: "qrc:/fnt/res/fnt/MuseoSans_500.otf"
}

FontLoader {
    id: museo100
    source: "qrc:/fnt/res/fnt/museo100-regular.ttf"
}
```

When accessing the fonts I set the font.family to museosans500.name and museo100.name. Like I said, they work fine on Android. But neither work on iOS, and only one of them works on Windows.

I'm using Qt Creator 3.4.0 and Qt 5.4.1.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I didn't solve it for Windows but this is an application for iOS and Android.
Basically I loaded the fonts through main.cpp instead with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Load custom fonts
    if(QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(QStringLiteral(":/fnt/res/fnt/MuseoSans_500.otf")) == -1)
        qDebug() << "Failed to load font Museo Sans 500";
    if(QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(QStringLiteral(":/fnt/res/fnt/museo100-regular.ttf")) == -1)
        qDebug() << "Failed to load font Museo 100";

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/res/qml/LoadScreen.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Originally this didn't actually work. But that's because I was setting the font.family to be "Museo Sans 500" and "Museo 100" since that is what Windows would print in console when I asked for a full list of available font families.

When I printed out the font families list in Android, Mac and iOS I actually got "Museo Sans" and "Museo" respectively. Changing the font.family to those strings worked fine.

Unfortunately I have found no solution for Windows yet, but like I've said that doesn't matter to me.